# PySpark: Create a subset of a dataframe for all dates

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a DataFrame that has a lot of columns and I need to create a subset of that DataFrame that has only date values.

For e.g. my Dataframe could be:

```
1, 'John Smith', '12/10/1982', '123 Main St', '01/01/2000'
2, 'Jane Smith', '11/21/1999', 'Abc St', '12/12/2020'
```

And my new DataFrame should only have:

```
'12/10/1982', '01/01/2000'
'11/21/1999', '12/12/2000'
```

The dates could be of any format and could be on any column. I can use the dateutil.parser to parse them to make sure they are dates. But not sure how to call parse() on all the columns and only filter those that return true to another dataframe, easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you columns the datetimes are in it's easy:

```py
pd2 = pd[["row_name_1", "row_name_2"]]
# or 
pd2 = pd.iloc[:, [2, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what columns could have dates..

Answer (score 0):

You can find your columns' datatype by checking each tuple in your_dataframe.dtypes.

```
schema = "id int, name string, date timestamp, date2 timestamp"
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "John", datetime.now(), datetime.today())], schema)

list_of_columns = []

for (field_name, data_type) in df.dtypes:
    if data_type == "timestamp":
        list_of_columns.append(field_name)
```

Now you can use this list inside .select()

```
df_subset_only_timestamps = df.select(list_of_columns)
```

EDIT: I realized your date columns might be StringType.
You could try something like:

```
df_subset_only_timestamps = df.select([when(col(column).like("%/%/%"), col(column)).alias(column) for column in df.columns]).na.drop()
```

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58420839/searching-for-substring-across-multiple-columns) answer. Let me know if it works!